# Read variables in URL as function in php

Tags: php, url

Started learning php this week  and had many doubts, but this is one of them which i couldn't find solution(Maybe i didn't know the right keyword to search for).

Is it possible to read variables in URL as a function inside a php file, 
for example :

```
  http://mywebsite.com/demo_app/phone_api/login/harsha/harshapass
```

Here demo_app is the folder, phone_api is the php file, and i want to invoke the function login, where harsha and harshapass is the paramaters to that function.

Comment: Do you intend on parsing this information or just having it magically do it all by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need 2 things for this.

The first is `mod_rewrite`, this is an apache module. With this module you can rewrite the URL like you want, so that /demo_app/phone_api/ will redirect to your php file.

I advice that you read a tutorial somewhere about this, for example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/).

Second thing is that you need to parse the URL.

With `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` you get the URL. With [explode](http://php.net/explode) and/or [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you can parse this string into the parts you want (function, parameters, whatever).

If you have a more specific question about this, you can ask this here (in a new topic).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider sending the values as `$_GET` variables and retrieving them in the page like so:

```
  http://mywebsite.com/demo_app/phone_api?login=login&harsha=harsha&harshapass=harshapass
```

so you can get the values in the phone_api.php page like:

```
$login = $_GET['login'];
$harsha = $_GET['harsha'];
$harshapass = $_GET['harshapass'];
$login($harsha, $harshapass){
  //your function code.
}
```

Maybe it'll be easier this way.

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that method and i know to use that way, But i'm looking for different method.